# Solving $\frac53\left(3-\frac{x}{5}\right) = x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Although I had already solved the following equation, I can't figure out why I fail when passing thru a $15$ denominator I get a bad result.

$$\frac53\cdot\left(3-\frac{x}{5}\right) = x$$

Transformation to get $15$ denominator:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{5\cdot 5(15\cdot 3-3x)}{15} &= \frac{15\cdot x}{15} \tag{1}\\[4pt]
25\cdot(45-3x) &= 15x \tag{2}\\
1125 - 75x &= 15x \tag{3}\\
1125 &= 90x \tag{4}\\[4pt]
x &= \frac{1125}{90} \tag{5}
\end{align}$$

Using alternative approaches, $x = 15/4 = 3.75$, which I believe is the right answer.

> What am I doing wrong on the above try?

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial for proper formatting

Comment: No need for a common denominator, just multiply out: $$\frac53\cdot\left(3-\frac{x}{5}\right)=5-x/3.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to multiply the left-hand numerator by 15.
Although you multiply top and bottom of the right hand side by 15, you don't  fo it to the left because the denominator is already 15.  So the numerator on the left is just $5(15-x)$

Comment: Although there were several valuable answers, this one targets that I was missing: left-handed side was already a good 15 denominator candidate, beside the fact that there was no reason to convert both factors to their least common multiple.

Answer (score 5):

Be careful. Too many steps at once maybe.

$$\frac53\left(3-\frac x5\right)=x.$$

[LCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_abbreviations) in parenthesis

$$\frac53\left(\frac{15-x}5\right)=x.$$

LCD on [RHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_abbreviations)

$$\frac{5(15-x)}{15}=\frac{15x}{15}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying both by $$\frac{3}{5}$$ we get
$$3-\frac{x}{5}=\frac{3}{5}x$$ so $$3=\frac{4}{5}x$$ thus
$$x=\frac{15}{4}$$

Comment: I loved the simplicity of your solution

Answer (score 2):

your first nominator is wrong, $$(3-\frac{x}{5})=\frac{15*3-3x}{15}$$ 
but then you multiply by $$\frac{5}{3}=\frac{25}{15}$$ id would give you 15^2 in the nominator. (best way is always to multiply with the common nominator , here 15) 
trula

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange, thank you for you contribution and for answering a question. I think the answer can be improved if you fix a few things:  (1) Please try to improve the language and fix a few typos (e.g., id $\rightarrow$ it) and please (2) fix Latex formatting (e.g., 15^2 $\rightarrow$ $15^2$)

Comment: In a fraction, you divide the numerator by the denominator. $$\frac{\text{numerator}}{\text{denominator}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your first line of working is wrong because
$$\frac53\left(3-\frac{x}5\right)\ne\frac{5\cdot5(15\cdot3-3x)}{15}$$
you should actually get
$$\frac53\left(3-\frac{x}5\right)=\frac{5\cdot5}{15}\cdot\frac{15\cdot3-3x}{15}$$